# Chamar Activity aberta através da Notificação sem perder as informações

Tags: java, android

Estou com problema em chamar uma Activit através do Notification, toda vez que pressiono a notificação a Activity é carregada do zero, perdendo os dados que estavam na que estava aberta.

```
        NotificationManagerCompat nm = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

    Intent it = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)

                    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, it, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_usuario)
                    .setContentTitle("Aplicativo")
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(2).setDefaults(1)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(2), 3);

    nm.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Eu só quero que a notificação chame a Activity que está aberta, vlw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente você está criando outra activity, teste colocar para a activity no seu manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Outro problema pode ser que você que você esteja limpando os dados no `OnStart()` ou `OnResume()`.

Comment: Resolveu com o `android:launchMode="singleTask"` vlw!